# google-maps-sdk-ios - arm 7/iphone 5 issues for Google Maps 1.4.3 for iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having issues getting my app referencing the Google Maps 1.4.3 sdk for iOS. There seems to be an issue with arm7 & 7s and it refuses to install onto the device (iphone 5) although it runs fine on the simulator. I believe I have followed google's documentation for the API Key, the frameworks needed, build settings - architecture etc & I'm still getting "xcode cannot run using the selected device.. choose a destination with a supported architecture.."

Comment: Did you follow step 7, "Replace the default value of Architectures with armv7", under "Adding the Google Maps SDK for iOS to your project"? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: Is this a common problem encountered when using 3rd party SDK's like Facebook SDK or Google Maps SDK on iOS?

Comment: Depends on the SDK. Google hasn't implemented support for armv7s yet. They indicated via their issue tracker that they will support it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I have `Architectures` set to `armv7` and `Valid Architectures` set to `armv7 armv7s`, for both the project and the target.

Are your settings the same?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to No, for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [Google mailing list](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4745), support for `armv7s` was added on September 20th, 2013. Download version 1.5 of the SK from [their website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start).