# iOS app won't build for iPad Air without 'armv7s' as a valid architecture

Tags: ios, xcode5, cocoapods

I have an iPad app that relies on the Google Maps iOS SDK. The Google Maps SDK is added as a cocoapod and it does not compile for 'armv7s' architecture, so when I first created the project, I had removed "armv7s" as a valid architecture.

Now, when I try to build the app for iPad Air, I get the following:

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).
```

If I set "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH" to 'NO', cocoapods will have massive issues (all pods will have the "undefined symbol for architecture" problem). If I add "armv7s" as a valid arch, Google Maps won't build. I know it's possible to use Google Maps on an iPad Air, but I can't figure it out. What do I have to change in my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581759/google-maps-sdk-ios-arm-7-iphone-5-issues-for-google-maps-1-4-3-for-ios), the [Google Maps SDK now has support for armv7s and if you pick up the latest version (which is 1.6.1 as I type this)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start), you should be just fine.

I would assume that with "`armv7s`" support in both the SDK and in your own code, you can keep "`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`" set to "`YES`" going forward.

Comment: Like I said, "Google Maps" won't build. On the Google Maps SDK page, it says you can't have "armv7s" as one of the architectures. Specific error is: "ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/.../Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps file '/Users/.../Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps' for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"